# Is it possible to create multiple collections out of a fork (e.g. bucket or facet)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I was wondering if it's possible to create multiple collections (3 to be precise) when using facet and/or bucket. The documentation specifies that facet can't be used with out. So is there an alternative? I'm trying to do something like the following:

1. Split document in 3 categories *(bucket / facet ???)*
2. With these categories get an avg of some value
3. Output the query to 3 different collections, each collection have the name of the category

I have the following atm, which groups and filters everything, but if I'm using *$out*, it can only export to one document (so I got rid of $out)

```
db.getCollection('metingen').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $unwind: "$parameters"
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id : { 
                    uur: { $hour: "$tijdstip" },            
                    locatie: { 
                        $map: { 
                            input: "$loc.coordinates",
                            in: { 
                                $divide: [
                                        { $trunc: { $multiply: [ '$$this', 1000 ] }}, 
                                        1000
                                ]
                            }                                        
                         }
                    }
                },
                gemiddelde: { 
                    $avg: "$parameters.value"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: { "_id.uur" : 1 }
        }
    ]
);
```

The filter value should be something like *$parameters.soort*, but I haven't added it here, but I experimented with it before. I'm looking for a way to do this in one query only if possible.

Thanks in advance!